# What is a word or idiom of describing "You had pick and bring some job/assignment of trouble to me?"

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

What is a word or idiom of describing "You had pick some job/assignment full of trouble to me?"

For example, situation can be your boss told you to bring a letter all the way from NY to california.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb **[single out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/single-sb-sth-out)** means to select somebody for special treatment- which could either be good or bad. For example:

> I don't know why my boss singled me out to take this letter to California!